# Find the volume of a parallelepiped spanned by the vertices $(1,1,1)$,$(4,8,3)$,$(1,3,2)$, and $(3,2,3)$

Tags: vectors

I am aware that the volume of a parallelepiped is found by finding the triple scalar product but what vectors do I use? Does it matter? Also, does it matter which order I cross or dot product those vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick one vertex (say $(1,1,1)$). Subtract it from each of the others to get three vectors. Use those.

*Then* ask yourself "Hey, wait a minute. What if I'd picked a different vertex as "basepoint"...would I have gotten the same result?" and figure out why the answer is "yes," using properties of determinants (or triple products).

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I have attempted (I was unsure as to whether that approach was legitimate). Does it matter which order they are crossed or dotted? I got an answer of 15 - is this right?

Comment: You can get positive and negative answers (but they will all have the same absolute value).

Comment: I'm not gonna do the arithmetic for you; sorry. The order of crossing and dotting doesn't matter (except for changing the sign); you might want to try to reason out why.